# In R how to remove small community from igraph

Tags: r, graph, igraph

in R network graph how to remove small community of twos (two nodes connected with one edge and no connection with other nodes, like jane and ike in this example:

```
library(igraph)
g <- graph_from_literal(Andre----Beverly:Diane:Fernando
                    Beverly--Garth:Ed,
                    Carol----Andre:Diane:Fernando,
                    Diane----Andre:Carol:Fernando:Beverly,
                    Fernando-Carol:Andre:Diane:Heather,
                    Jane-----Ike )
plot(g, vertex.label.color="blue", vertex.label.cex=1.5,
 vertex.label.font=2, vertex.size=25, vertex.color="white",
 vertex.frame.color="white", edge.color="black")
```

Answer (score 8):

Here's a possible solution using `components` to find subgraphs and then doing some counting.  You could also look into functions from `igraph` such as `groups` and `sizes` to do these operations of getting subgraph vertex count and vertex names.

```
library(igraph)
g <- graph_from_literal(Andre----Beverly:Diane:Fernando,
                        Beverly--Garth:Ed,
                        Carol----Andre:Diane:Fernando,
                        Diane----Andre:Carol:Fernando:Beverly,
                        Fernando-Carol:Andre:Diane:Heather,
                        Jane-----Ike )

#get all subgraphs
sub_gs <- components(g)$membership

#find which subgraphs have 2 nodes
small_sub <- names(which(table(sub_gs) == 2))

#get names of nodes to rm
(rm_nodes <- names(which(sub_gs == small_sub)))
# [1] "Jane" "Ike" 

#remove nodes by name
g2 <- delete_vertices(g, rm_nodes)
```

Comment: This was a helpful example. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

We can use `induced_subgraph` + `membership` like below to filterout the clusters of small size (e.g., size 2 or even smaller)

```
induced_subgraph(
  g,
  V(g)[ave(1:vcount(g), membership(components(g)), FUN = length) > 2]
)
```